# Javascript dragging

Tags: javascript

i was trying to make a drag able  element but i failed...
i don't want to use jquery.

i got the following html code:

```
<div id='area'>
  <div id='drag'></div>
</div>
```

i want to drag id='drag' inside id='area' and not going out of it.

sorry for my bad English and for my newbie question.

EDIT:

```
Area.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    var X, Y;
    X = e.offsetX;
    Y = e.offsetY;
    Information.innerHTML = 'X:' + X + ' - ' + 'Y:' + Y;
});

img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    this.style.cursor = 'move';
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        var X, Y;
        X = e.offsetX;
        Y = e.offsetY;
        Information2.innerHTML = 'X:' + X + ' - ' + 'Y:' + Y;
    });
});
```

idk how to get the X and Y of the Area to add it to img

Comment: Can you use HTML5 or should this work using plain javascript on a dinosaur like IE say 6 or 7?

Comment: yes please i want it to support IE too.

Comment: Which version of IE do you want to support?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov "on a dinosaur like IE say 6 or 7" cannot stop laughing! :)

Comment: So you can't use HTML5 (because of the browser) :-) You can't use jQuery (for some unknown reason) => be prepared to suffer.

Comment: @Bahaazahika I think you didn't understand stackoverflow.com . First: Edit your question: make it readable and use valid English words. Also, keep the discussion public.

Comment: @Bahaazahika, no I don't have time for chatting and instead of wasting your time chattering open a javascript tutorial, start reading  and get into coding. And if you encounter some specific problem, don't hesitate to show your progress so far and we can see if we can help.

Comment: so your you saying you won't help ?

Comment: No, I didn't say that at all. What I said is that I won't write the code for you. I want to see what you have tried so far before being able to help you. That's how StackOverflow works. If you are looking for someone writing the code for you, you might hire a javascript developer.

Comment: i already search for tutorials i didnt found any thing
i did smth but i am stuck at part and no thank you i don't want to hire

Comment: At which part are you stuck? Could you show your progress so far? Nobody on StackOverflow is going to write the code for you.

Comment: ok look up i will edit

what a nice welcoming for new user..

Comment: ok its seems im not welcomed here i will find another site to help...

Comment: @Bahaazahika, not that's not true. You are very Welcome. Especially now that you have shown your code. You have to be more patient. Someone might be able to answer your question now. But don't think that your questions will be answered immediately.

Comment: This question is now the No2 result on google for the terms `javascript drag` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. I found this online. I think this what you are looking for :

[**Javascript Draggable**](http://jsfiddle.net/JxKpg/1/)